# Joomla 1.5 with FlexiContent : API usable in code to import content from CSV in Joomla?

Tags: csv, import, components, joomla1.5

I'm new to Joomla 1.5 and have to create a component in charge of importing data from a CSV file. These data are custom content types, and after a few searches I selected FlexiContent which seems perfect to create my types.

Now I want to import the data I got on CSV in the CMS with all their custom fields, within the good custom type. So far, no trace of documentation about how to do it "properly".

I found links about people inserting manually in database data, but I'l sure there is a safe way to do it using Flexicontent framework.
The Flexicontent forum seems broken on registration and I cannot ask here...

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try latest version of FLEXIcontent ?
it has improved CSV import for Content Items
-- with many more options/capabilities and 
-- more user-friendly debugging of the import process

Comment: Thanks, I decided to change my point of view and totally develop what I needed (small CCK and import tools)